# I played mid against a Ryze as Kassadin and got destroyed

Tags: league-of-legends

I started out alright but he kept snaring me and htting me with skills, getting me below half hp with one combo. It got really bad and he was doubling my CS. Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Ryze's snare > Your silence. As long as he estimates the cooldown on your combo (incl. silence), a good Ryze will shut Kassadin down any time. Ryze can't 1 vs 2, so next time call for ganks often and he will snare one of you, and be vulnerable to the other. I main Ryze and believe that I win mid lane 90% of the time and top 80%.

Comment: It's only a snare, not a stun.

Comment: I'll edit my post to snare, thanks :) Either way, if Ryze snares Kassadin, Ryze can out range Kassadin and Kassadin wouldn't be able to ulti out in time to deny Ryze's combo.

Comment: Well, can't Kassadin get his silence of right after the snare making ryze unable to preform his combo and give kassadin some time to escape?

Comment: Ryze can probably throw away at least one spell after snare since Kassadin's silence is a projectile.

Comment: @RobinCastlin Yes, but see if Ryze comes for you, you know he will start with the snare... so right when you are snared the projectile will hit, because you have forseen him doing so. And didn't his silence get a faster movement?

Comment: King Ryze is stronk. But seriously, Ryze is borderline overpowered and can easily dish more damage than most mid champions. The best you can do is ultimate on top of him so you are in range when he snares you. Keep in mind him casting spells increases your attack speed like mad and also charges your E, so from there you can slow him and hammer at him with your auto-attack **even when snared**. It sounds lame but you also probably want to tank Kassadin when facing Ryze - grab some items like Chalice of Harmony to give extra MR and help you regen mana so you can at least farm with your Q.

Comment: Also don't forget that when you are targeted by someone they are outlined in yellow! This can help you predict when Ryze is going for you a little better, so at least you can silence him and prevent him from doing too much damage.